# add pictures to the project through a zip

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

I have an application that takes up too much space and I would like to lower the weight, so I had decided to put all the images in a zip file and install it in the application rather than adding the images to the project. Is it possible, or does someone have a better idea? thanks

Comment: That sounds like it would only reduce the download size, not the actual space the app takes up (it would probably take up more space this way - the zipped version + unizipped). Is that your intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compressing the images by putting them in a zip, given they're already in a compressed format (.jpg, .gif, .png, etc.), should not yield any appreciable gain in the size of the app, considering the effort to build the mechanism, the time it takes to unzip the files and the space in memory to keep a copy of the ucompressed files.

I would rather suggest compressing properly the images, by reducing the quality or trying with different file formats (like JPG2000).

Comment: That is a good point. I have also had good luck with [PNGOut](http://www.advsys.net/ken/utils.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) and unzip the files within your app:

```
- (void)UnzippingZipFile {

    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/FolderName"];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"ZipFile.zip"];
    NSString *zipPath = filePath;

    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:outputPath delegate:self];

}
```